# Stata vs. R: Substantial difference in memory usage during pooled OLS (Panel)

Tags: r, memory, time-series, regression, stata

I am attempting to run a pooled OLS regression on a panel dataset of about 34,000 observations. When calling lm() in R, this process takes forever and ends up consuming over 30GB of memory (hence, it goes out-of-RAM whilst estimating the regression). In fact, I had to force quit the program as my computer almost crashed.

When I run the exact same regression in Stata (on the same dataset), this process takes roughly 1 second. I do not follow what is going on here, am I doing something wrong?

R Code:

```
pooled1=lm(ret ~ l_ret + l_btm + l_roe, data=panel)
```

Stata Code:

```
reg ret l_ret l_btm l_roe, r
```

[image: Stata Output]

[image: R Memory Usage]

[image: Stata Browser]

[image: R Browser]

[image: str(Panel)]

[image: summary(panel)]

Comment: Trying to reproduce your problem in R. `lm(a ~ b + c, data = data.frame(a = rnorm(34000, 5, 2), b = rnorm(34000, 7, 2), c = c(rep(1, 17000), rep(2, 17000))))` takes less than a second on my computer. Do you manage to produce an example dataset that causes similar issue?

Comment: Dear @Mikko, 

Thank you for answering. Indeed, your reproduction works fine for me in R. Hence, there must clearly be something else going on. Looking at the data browsers for R and Stata, however, the loaded dataset (panel) is displayed identically... (I have updated the post with screenshots of these).

Comment: Please paste `str()` and `summary()` results of your data.frame.

Comment: convert `l_ret` to numeric and try again

Comment: Ah of course. Interesting how Stata appears to do this automatically. Thank you @missuse and Mikko ! I will update the post with the solution.

Comment: Are you by any chance using R 3.1.0? If so, you're experiencing a bug tied to non-conversion of numeric values that would result in loss during data import.  I would recommend an R update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$l_ret` variable is a character vector. Try converting it to a numeric vector `Panel$l_ret <- as.numeric(Panel$l_ret)`, and run your analysis again. Also your data.frame is a [`tibble`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tibble/versions/1.3.4/topics/tibble-package) object. This should not slow R down, but you might also want to try converting `Panel` to a data.frame to minimize any interference. You can do this by `Panel <- as.data.frame(Panel)`.

Comment: Thank you Mikko. I had just assumed that since Stata could run the analysis, the actual dataset configuration would also check out fine. Lesson learnt.

Comment: You probably have either a letter string or a number with a comma (0,5  f.ex) among those 34000 numbers. That's why it gets converted to a character vector.